# parse CSV in Flask-Admin/WTForms on model_change

Tags: python, csv, wtforms, filefield, flask-admin

Suppose the `Flask-Admin` view below (note I'm using `flask_wtf` not `wtforms`). I'd like to upload a `csv` file, and then on the `model_change`, parse the csv and do some stuff to it before returning the result which will then be stored into the model. However, I get the error: `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, FileField found`

```
from flask_wtf.file import FileField

class myView(ModelView):
    [...]
    def scaffold_form(self):
        form_class = super(myView, self).scaffold_form()
        form_class.csv = FileField('Upload CSV')
        return form_class

    def on_model_change(self, form, model):
        csv = form.csv
        csv_data = self.parse_file(csv)
        model.csv_data = csv_data

    def parse_file(self, csv):
        with open(csv, 'rb') as csvfile:
            data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

            for row in data:
                doSomething()
```

When accessing `csv.data`, I'll get `<FileStorage: u'samplefile.csv' ('text/csv')>` but this object doesn't actually contain the csv's data.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after digging further into the `flask_wtf` module I was able to find enough to go on and get a workaround. The [`FileField` object](http://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/form.html#module-flask_wtf.file) has a `data` attribute that wraps the [`werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage) class which exposes the `stream` attribute. The docs say this typically points to the open file resource, but since I'm doing this in memory in this case it's a stream buffer [`io.BytesIO` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BytesIO).

Attempting to `open()`:

```
with open(field.data.stream, 'rU') as csv_data:
    [...]
```

Will result in an `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, _io.BytesIO found`.

BUT, `csv.reader` can also [take a string or buffer directly](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples), so we pass in the straight shootin' buffer to the `csv.reader`:

```
buffer = csv_field.data.stream # csv_field is the FileField obj
csv_data = csv.reader(buffer, delimiter=',')

for row in csv_data:
    print row
```

I found it interesting that if you need additional coercion to/from `Unicode UTF-8`, the csv examples in docs [provides a snippet on wrapping an encoder/decoder](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples).

Answer (score 0):

For me, this did the trick:

```
def on_model_change(self, form, model):
        tweet_file = form.tweet_keywords_file
        buffer = tweet_file.data.stream 
        file_data =  buffer.getvalue()
```